# How to insert image src with while loop in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to insert image src with while loop in javascript

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var i=1;
  while(i <= 40)
  {
    document.getElementByClassName("fruit").src += "path" + i + ".png";
    i+=1;
  }
});
```

```html
<img class="img-responsive" src="path/1.png" />
<img class="img-responsive" src="path/2.png" />
<img class="img-responsive" src="path/3.png" />
...
<img class="img-responsive" src="path/40.png" />
```

How to create this series with javascript

Comment: Add different `id` for each image, and use `getElementById`. Or use `$.each` function of jQuery

Comment: `$('<img />').attr('src', 'path' + i + '.png').appendTo($('.fruit'))`.

Comment: And anyway, as @h2ooooooo wrote, why do you use pure javascript if you are using `jQuery`?

Comment: @h2ooooooo, can you give the complete code in fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to look at the collection of elements with the class name first, rather than evaluate the collection with each pass through the while loop.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 0;
    var elementCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('img-responsive');
    var max_i = elementCollection.length;
    while(i < 40 && i < max_i) {
        elementCollection[i].src = "path/" + i + ".png";
        i+=1;
    }
});
```

Comment: <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
      var i = 0;
      var elementCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('fruit');
      var max_i = elementCollection.length;
      while(i < 40 && i < max_i) {
       elementCollection[i].src = "images/home_icons/fruits/" + i + ".png";
       i+=1;
      }
     });
    </script>
                <img class="img-responsive fruit" src="images/home_icons/fruits/1.png" />



This is my final code, but there is not success.